# How to get Country Code from timezone ID in java?

Tags: java, timezone

```
 String zoneId = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().toZoneId();
```

I want to get String[] which is having the countries ISO code  e.g. "AS", "AL", "AU" for which the zoneId is applicable ?

Comment: Does this make sense? There are more countries for a single timezone... see the javadocs of ZoneIds: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html

Comment: It doesn’t compile since `toZoneId()` returns a `ZoneId` (not a `String`; but you may append `.toString()` to have one). @Paolof76: It makes sense if the zone ID is in the region/city format, for example, Pacific/Honolulu, which it ought to be. But I’m afraid it will require somewhat of a geography database.

Comment: Is there any third party api or something which will convert "region/city" format into the respective country ISO code or country name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the best alternative is to get these IANA's files:

- https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/main/zone.tab
- https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/main/zone1970.tab

Those files have entries in the format below:

```
#codes  coordinates TZ  comments
AD      +4230+00131 Europe/Andorra
AE,OM   +2518+05518 Asia/Dubai
AF      +3431+06912 Asia/Kabul
```

If I'm not wrong, `zone1970.tab` is newer and covers cases where a timezone is used by more than one country, but you can check both and see which one solves your problem.

And there's also [the iso3166.tab file](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/main/iso3166.tab) that maps countries codes to their respective names.

I'm not sure if Java has an API that directly reads those files, but looking at their formats, it seems to be straighforward to read them and find the info you want.

**Quick note**: there's no need to call `Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().toZoneId()`.

If you want your JVM's default timezone as a `ZoneId` object, just call `ZoneId.systemDefault()`. If you want the zone's ID as a `String` (such as `Europe/Berlin` or `America/New_York`), just call `ZoneId.systemDefault().getId()`.